# Add text in separate lines in shinydashboard sidebar

Tags: html, r, shinydashboard

Im trying to put text in separate lines in shinydashboard sidebar I cant make it work with `<br>`:

```
library(shiny)


# Creating a Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Subset Data by Date Range"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      textOutput("date_range_text")
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$date_range_text <- renderText({
    
      
      paste('<br>','Minimum for Selected Topic:',5,"</br>",
            'Maximum for Selected Topic:',5)
      
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Rather than using `textOuput/renderText`, use `uiOuput/renderUI` and be sure to wrap your string with `HTML()`, ie, `HTML(paste(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the use of <br> with the HTML function. Updated code is here

```
library(shiny)

# Creating a Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Subset Data by Date Range"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      htmlOutput("date_range_text")  # Use htmlOutput instead of textOutput
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$date_range_text <- renderText({
    
    # Use HTML function to include HTML tags
    HTML(paste('Minimum for Selected Topic:', 5, "<br>",
               'Maximum for Selected Topic:', 10))
      
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```